# display center columns in another row in bootstrap in mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a row with three columns in desktop view
now I want to display middle column under other two columns in a new row
as shown below : [image]

my code for desktop view :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
         A
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         B
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         C
      </div>
  </div>
```

How do I write code for col-sm-  ?

What should I do?

Comment: Can you post a html snippet of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please add your code. See the [How to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Ask page for help.

Comment: @user3115252 i answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can use order-sm-last class from bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
         A
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 order-sm-last">
         B
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
         C
      </div>
  </div>
```

**[Live Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/b1z73cap/)**

Comment: Hi  Tzimpo, Unfortunately, my Bootstrap version is below 4

Comment: You didn't delare it on your question. Your tag is bootstrap-4. If you are using Bootstrap 3 read about push/pull on sm screens

Comment: Thank you Tzimpo